# Tuple2 and tuple of two elements : what are their differences?

Tags: scala

In the following code, why type mismatch happened?

```
scala> val lb = ListBuffer[Tuple2[Int, Int]]()
lb: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ListBuffer()

scala> lb += (1, 2)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: (Int, Int)
              lb += (1, 2)
                     ^

scala> lb += Tuple2(1, 2)
res43: lb.type = ListBuffer((1,2))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your writing

```
lb += (1, 2)
```

It's actually doing this, you called += method with two integer arguments, where it should be one Tuple2[Int, Int]:

```
lib.+=(1, 2)
```

To fix this, add another () around (1, 2) like the following:

```
lb += ((1, 2))
lib.+=((1, 2))
```

Answer (score 9):

Brian's answer is right, but I recommend to write it like that:

```
lb += 1 -> 2
```

There is an implicit convertion from `Any` to `ArrowAssoc`, which has method `->` :

```
class ArrowAssoc[A](val x: A) {
    def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(x, y)
  }
```